# Difference between ? and !, memory management

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references

I was going through the Swift ARC Guide and I tried below code in 
playground

```
class Person {
    let name: String
    init(name: String) { self.name = name }
    var apartment: Apartment?
    deinit { print("\(name) is being deinitialized") }
}

class Apartment {
    let unit: String
    init(unit: String) { self.unit = unit }
    weak var tenant: Person?
    deinit { print("Apartment \(unit) is being deinitialized") }
}

var john: Person?
var unit4A: Apartment?

john = Person(name: "John Appleseed")
unit4A = Apartment(unit: "4A")

john!.apartment = unit4A 

unit4A!.tenant = john

john = nil
unit4A = nil
```

Above code is not calling `deinit` if I use `!` but it calls `deinit` if I use `?`, why?

```
john?.apartment = unit4A

unit4A?.tenant = john
```

I am using swift 4.2 and Xocde 10.1

Comment: Which line are you referring to?

Comment: @rmaddy second and third from last. John!.apartment = unit4A 

unit4A!.tenant = John, if I use `?` instead `!` then it calls deinit()

Comment: How are you running that code? I put both in a macOS playground with Xcode 10.3 and `deinit` was called for both.

Comment: @CraigSiemens in iOS playground